# Estimated standard error vs standard error

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-error

My statistics text is trying to define "estimated standard error" by an example, but I'd like a real definition so I can mentally keep it distinguished from just "standard error." It reads:

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ and let $\hat{p}_n = n^{-1}\sum_i X_i$. Then $\mathbb{E}(\hat{p}_n) = n^{-1}\sum_i \mathbb{E}(X_i) = p$ so $\hat{p}_n$ is unbiased. The **standard error** is $se = \sqrt{\mathbb{V}(\hat{p}_n)} = \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$. The **estimated standard error** is $\hat{se} = \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}$.

Based on knowing $\mathbb{E}(\hat{p}_n)$ I can do the algebra to derive $\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(\hat{p}_n)} = \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ and I can understand $se = \sqrt{\mathbb{V}(\hat{p}_n)}$ as just being what the definition of the standard error of a point estimator is.

I am unclear however how to make the jump to the formula for $\hat{se}$ other than "swap in the best estimate for the variable you need but don't have", i.e. $\hat{p}_n$ for $p$, but that doesn't sound like a formal definition. Is that all that's going on here? It doesn't seem to be being done rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

$\hat{p}$ is not only unbiased but it is a consistent estimator, i. e. $ P(|\hat{p} − p| > \epsilon) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

There is a property for consistent estimators that states that if $\theta = g(p)$ then $\hat{\theta} = g(\hat{p})$ is also a consistent estimator

So in this case $se = \sqrt{p(1-p)/n} = g(p) $ so $\hat{se} = g(\hat{p}) = \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}$

You have to take into account that this property only states that it is a consistent estimator, that does not mean that it is unbiased or have any other good property.

Comment: How general is the proof? It's true for consistent estimators of any parameter of any distribution?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. CONSISTENT

Comment: What is important is the distribution of the estimator.  This is a general property that applies for any CONSISTENT estimator ( at least for estimators with finite variance for sure)

Comment: Do you know where I could read more about this? "Transformation of consistent estimator is consistent" doesn't seem to get me much on Google.

Comment: Invariance property of maximum likelihood estimators

Comment: Found this: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Consistent_estimator Apparently the function must also be continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, any estimator of the true standard error can be considered an *estimated standard error*.  In this case the estimator is formed by just substituting the point estimator $\hat{p}$ for $p$, but it would be possible to use another estimator if you prefer.  There is no one single definition of the estimated standard error, because there is no one single *estimator*.